# Crawling desktop on Ubuntu 14.04.2 server on an Intel S1200v3RPS server board

Tags: unity, server, graphics, intel

I asked this question earlier but have more specific situation to report.

I have this new S1200v3RPS motherboard and it runs fine with Ubuntu except when it comes to using the Desktop. The desktop is effectively unusable because of the slowness.

Here is what I tried:

- Change monitors. Had no effect.
- Installed the Intel Linux Graphics driver utility (from 01.org)
- Tried using 14.10 Ubuntu instead of 14.04
- I was running the Server edition of Ubuntu and then installing the desktop minimal using the no-recommends... option.  Instead tried installing Ubuntu Desktop.
- I have all versions I have tried here working on an old Intel motherboard with a lot slower CPU and the desktop works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I really need to get this server board to work with Ubuntu and I need the desktop to function minimally!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-mga
```

it will remove the xserver-xorg-video-mga and xserver-xorg-video-all
then reboot
now the window not slowly, and screen only has a 800x600 @75hz , but it work fine